# flutter - errors event.snapshot.value since updating to firebase 9.0.X

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting errors on `event.snapshot.value` since updating to firebase 9.0.5.
I have many functions like this which worked fine in firebase 8.X.

```
  Stream<List<MentorModel>> mentorStream() {
    final stream = _database.onValue;

    final Stream<List<MentorModel>> resultStream = stream.map((event) {
      List<MentorModel> _mentorList = [];
      Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value).forEach((key, value) => _mentorList.add(MentorModel.fromRTDB(key, value)));
      return _mentorList;
    });

    return resultStream;
  }
```

Now I have error marks on `event.snapshot.value`, and android studio says

```
Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
      Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value).forEach((key, value) => _mentorList.add(MentorModel.fromRTDB(key, value)));
```

When I try

```
Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((key, value) =>
```

then the error marker is gone but when I run the app it returns

```
E/flutter (16737): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast, stack trace:
```

What exactly changed in firebase 9.0? How can I iterate through event.snapshot.value in firebase 9.0?

Comment: Firebase v9 is functional and v8 and bellow is OOP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Firebase v9, they moved from using `dynamic` to `Object?` and it can be quite an hassle to start converting `Object?` to `Map` as you have experienced..Simply making the the object `dynamic` would remove the hassle.

Try:

```
Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as dynamic).forEach((key, value) => _mentorList.add(MentorModel.fromRTDB(key, value)));
```

Comment: It works! And I have no idea why it works. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: From Firebase v9, the moved from using `dynamic` to `Object?` and it can be quite an hassle to start converting `Object?` to `Map` as you have experienced..Simply making the the object `dynamic` would remove the hassle.

Comment: ```event.snapshot.value as dynamic``` works but ```snapshot.value as dynamic``` doesn't. Code looks like this:
```FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('/users/$userID').get().then((snapshot) {
      return UserProfileModel.fromRTDB(userID, snapshot.value as dynamic);``` Any idea?

Comment: What error does it throw?
Can you make this a separate question so it doesn't get clumsy?

Comment: Never mind. Solved with ```Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as dynamic)```

Comment: Can anyone post full code? Thx

Comment: Full code posted @Misho

Comment: Hm, on my code not working.
`itemRef.once().then((event) {
final _data1 = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as dynamic).forEach((key, value) => _notes.add(Item.fromRTDB(value)));
 });`

Comment: Can you ask it as a separate question and send the link?

Comment: [The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932672/flutter-realtime-database-9-0-6-listobject-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-mapdyn)

Comment: @Josteve could you please take a look here ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996336/unable-to-read-node-changes-when-the-stream-will-fire-a-new-event-firebase-data

Answer (score 0):

statut: json['statut'] != null ? (json['statut'] as List).map((i) => Statut.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(i as dynamic))).toList() : null,