# Flutter realtime database 9.0.6 List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

After update Firebase Realtime Database to 9.0.X I cant converet snapshot.value to Map<dynamic, dynamic> or Map<String, dynamic>

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance; 
database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);

itemRef = database.reference().child('_child1').child(_remoteConfigService.getStringLang);

itemRef.once().then((event) {
    final _data1 = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as dynamic).forEach((key, value) => 
_notes.add(Item.fromRTDB(value)));
});
```

My Model Class:

```
class Item {
  String key;
  String code;
  String spn;

  Item({
    required this.key,
    required this.code,
    required this.spn});

  factory Item.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Item(
         key: data['key'] ?? '01',
        code: data['code'] ?? 'A drink',
        spn: data['spn'] ?? 'Beer');
  }

  toJson() {
    return {
      "key": key,
      "code": code,
      "spn": spn,
    };
  }
}
```

In all options I get error:

```
List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the `key`s in the child are all numbers so it's already a `List`

Try this:

```
 final _data1 = List.from(event.snapshot.value as dynamic).forEach((key, value) => 
_notes.add(Item.fromRTDB(value)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. Only correction in my class need be: `Item.fromRTDB(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future<Null> getStudies() async {
_data.clear();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("etudes");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("type").equalTo(1);
// Get the Stream
Stream<DatabaseEvent> stream = query.onValue;
// Subscribe to the stream!
stream.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
  print('Event Type: ${event.type}'); // DatabaseEventType.value;
  print('Snapshot: ${event.snapshot}'); // DataSnapshot
  if(event.snapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(event.snapshot.value)) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    data.forEach((key, value)  async {
      _data.add(Etude.fromJson(value));
    });
    notifyListeners();
  } else {
    //print("snapshot does not exists");
    _loading  = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
});
notifyListeners();
return null;
```

}