# Unable to read node changes when the Stream will fire a new event. firebase database v9

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Works fine with firebase database v8 and not on v9. From what I read from other users -Firebase v9, they moved from using dynamic to Object? .
I can't implement the changes in my code.
Could you please take a look? More of this on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741649/flutter-errors-event-snapshot-value-since-updating-to-firebase-9-0-x)

```
     StreamSubscription<DatabaseEvent>? rideStreamSubscription;
      rideStreamSubscription = rideRequestRef!.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) async {
       
        if (event.snapshot.value["car_details"] != null) {
          carDetailsDriver = (event.snapshot.value["car_details"].toString());
          Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
              .carDetailsDriverMainScreen(carDetailsDriver);

          if (event.snapshot.value!["driver_id"] != null) {
            rideReqAcceptDriver =
                (event.snapshot.value["driver_id"].toString());
            print("rideReqAcceptDriver $rideReqAcceptDriver");
          }
        }
```

errors are on `event.snapshot.value["car_details"]`

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

and on `event.snapshot.value!["driver_id"]`

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try defining the operator '[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
StreamSubscription<DatabaseEvent>? rideStreamSubscription;
  rideStreamSubscription = rideRequestRef!.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) async {
    dynamic data = event.snapshot.value;
    if (data["car_details"] != null) {
      carDetailsDriver = (data["car_details"].toString());
      Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
          .carDetailsDriverMainScreen(carDetailsDriver);

      if (data["driver_id"] != null) {
        rideReqAcceptDriver =
            (data["driver_id"].toString());
        print("rideReqAcceptDriver $rideReqAcceptDriver");
      }
    }
```